# Do we have any video proof or some real place where baba/sadhus showing miracles?

Tags: shakti, siddhi

I have heard neem karoli baba/ Sai Baba had miraculous powers. But I haven't seen for myself. Is there a video or some sadhu/baba still showing miracles?

Comment: I have not seen any video showing a miracle or any of the sorts. If you find any let me know!

Comment: sai baba did in video.. several video are there for sai baba

Comment: @PrasannaR Do you have links to the video's which you can post here?

Comment: Yogi Prahlad Jani could miraculously survive without consuming food and water , by the grace of Godess Amba , for about a period of 70 yrs. Wikipedia has the details.A documentary on this account is a video proof. Here is the [link](https://m.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=7&v=_jLR3KaATUM&embeds_euri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.lightdocumentary.com%2F&source_ve_path=Mjg2NjY&feature=emb_logo).

Comment: Why do you want to even know about miracles? That is not even what hinduism preaches or even encourages....Even though i know of many of such personalities personally there is no need for siddhis to come under public eye because it takes away the main purpose of spirituality itself and distracts the seeker....